# Setting Custom Privacy When Posting On The User's Wall - Limit Post Visibility To Specific Users

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know the basics of how to post a status update, link, etc. from within a Facebook application, thanks to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/, but I can't figure out whether it's possible to limit the post's visibility to a certain preset list of friends of the user authorizing the post (since the documentation on Facebook's site isn't exactly the best).

Is it possible to post to the user's wall from within my application so that it's only visible to a pre-selected list of friends? I'm mimicking the functionality of Google Plus's "Circles" feature, where the user can have various groups of friends and post to only those group lists.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is definitely possible. Please read the [Post](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) documentation, especially the `privacy` parameter:

> object containing the **`value`** field and optional **`friends`**, **`networks`**,
>   **`allow`** and **`deny`** fields.
>
> The **`value`** field may specify one of the following strings: **`EVERYONE`**,
>   **`ALL_FRIENDS`**, **`NETWORKS_FRIENDS`**, **`FRIENDS_OF_FRIENDS`**, **`CUSTOM`** .
>
> The **`friends`** field must be specified if **`value`** is set to **`CUSTOM`** and
>   contain one of the following strings: **`EVERYONE`**, **`NETWORKS_FRIENDS`** (when
>   the object can be seen by networks and friends), **`FRIENDS_OF_FRIENDS`**,
>   **`ALL_FRIENDS`**, **`SOME_FRIENDS`**, **`SELF`**, or **`NO_FRIENDS`** (when the object can be
>   seen by a network only).
>
> The **`networks`** field may contain a comma-separated list of network IDs
>   that can see the object, or 1 for all of a user's network.
>
> The **`allow`** field must be specified when the **`friends`** value is set to
>   **`SOME_FRIENDS`** and must specify a comma-separated list of user IDs and
>   friend list IDs that 'can' see the post.
>
> The **`deny`** field may be specified if the **`friends`** field is set to
>   **`SOME_FRIENDS`** and must specify a comma-separated list of user IDs and
>   friend list IDs that 'cannot' see the post.
>
> Note: This privacy setting only applies to posts to the current or
>   specified user's own Wall. Facebook ignores this setting for targeted
>   Wall posts (when the user is writing on the Wall of a friend, Page,
>   event, group connected to the user). Consistent with behavior on
>   Facebook, all targeted posts are viewable by anyone who can see the
>   target's Wall.
>
> Privacy Policy: Any non-default privacy setting must be intentionally
>   chosen by the user

A small example using the PHP-SDK:

```
<?php
require '../src/311/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'APP_SECRET',
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    $privacy = array(
        'value' => 'CUSTOM',
        'friends' => 'SOME_FRIENDS',
        'allow' => 'XXXXXXX,YYYYYYY' // Change this to your friends ids
    );
    $params = array();
    $params['privacy'] = json_encode($privacy);
    $params['message'] = "Special for TWO friends";
    $post_id = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', $params);
    var_dump($post_id);
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    print_r($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}
?>
```

What I've done here:

1. Created 4 test accounts
2. Switched to one of them "Barbara"
3. Went to my app and logged in (with `publish_stream` permission)
4. Run the above code and the result:
   [image]
5. I've specified two friends (Ruth and Linda)
6. Now we switch to the 4th friend (Dorothy) and check Barbara's wall and... indeed the post is not visible. :-)

Please note that you have a lot of options here, you can deny specific user, allow networks, allow Friends list...it's really up to you to customize the `value`, `friends`, `allow`, `deny` and `networks` fields.

Comment: You are posting on /me/feed, not on /XXXXXXX/feed

Comment: @NicolasGrasset: that's what the OP meant. Posting on the users wall (the application is posting on the user's behalf) - The user is posting on his wall.

Comment: @NicolasGrasset: it's ok, and by the way what you mentioned is described in the quote from Facebook above.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. Thank you so much, ifaour!

Comment: TerranRich: you are welcome! Please read my comment on @Kasper's answer too!

Answer (score 0):

ifaours answer is really nice. One "problem" is that Facebook generally encourages you to let the user choose when to post on their or others walls by showing a post dialog.

If you are using the Javascript API you can use the FB.ui method with a feed parameter like in this link http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/

If you are not worried with following the recommended standards or have some other reason, like you don't want the user to take too many actions, I suggest you go with ifaours answer though :)

Comment: Obviously the best action the dev can use is not "programmatically" set the privacy and instead having a simple friend,friends list and network selector so that the user can choose the privacy and the dev (his code) will act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

**No, this is not possible.** Facebook Graph API will reply with an error saying you cannot set the privacy option when posting on another user's feed.

You can either post to your own feed with limited privacy like @ifaour describes if the post is meant to be secret, and hope Facebook will consider it relevant for the frontpage newsfeed, but it will not generate a notification by email.